# What is a Relation?

Tags: relations

In discrete math we define the relation as a sets of pairs of numbers, I understand when we write (a,b) we mean that (a) and (b) are realted what I don't grasp at all why the realtion between two diffrent is a subset of all ordered pairs between these sets. What is our intuition behind this definition?

Comment: It's just what you have said:  Letting $R$ be the relation in question, $a\sim_R b$ is the same as saying that the ordered pair $(a,b)$ is in the relation $R$.

Comment: Do you mean "relation"?

Comment: @lulu
but we have said that (a) is realted to (b) but we have not define the realtion itself

Comment: @kimchilover 
yes

Comment: I don't understand.  This is *notation*.  It holds for any relation $R$.  It does not define the relation.

Comment: Then you should correct your typo.

Comment: @lulu 
so what really defines the relation because i don't understand the concept of realtion at all

Comment: Well, that's a different question.  One which has nothing to do with the notation used to describe  the relation.  Presumably your reference materials have examples.  And [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)) is another discussion.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518906/reflexivity-how-can-something-be-related-to-itself/518935#518935

Answer (score 0):

First, think about some relations that you will be very familiar with such as $=$ and $\le$.

Let us also for simplicity use our underlying set as the integers, $\mathbb{Z}$. If we say that our relation, $R$, is $=$ then we have that $nRm$ iff $n=m$. So the only ordered pairs in the corresponding subset of ordered pairs are those of the form $(n,n)$. So $R=\{(n,n) | n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

Now, what about the relation $nRm$ iff $n\le m$.

As an exercise you tell me whether $(0,1), (8,3)$ or $(-2,-2)$ are in the corresponding subset.

Comment: it will be the ordered pair (0,1)

Comment: @Masoncarlos is that the only pair?

Comment: i didn't notice the equal it will be (0,1) and (-2,-2)

Comment: Yeah indeed. So do you see how those ordered pairs are within the subset. So the relation is just the entire subset where the ordered pair has the appropriate form.

Comment: but the ordered pairs (a,b) just says (a) and (b) is realted to each other how can we translate these ordered pairs to a realtion ?

Comment: i mean there is a diffrence between two things related to each other and the realtion itself

Comment: I think you are over stating this difference. The relation defines what things are related. The subset of ordered pairs is a list of all elements which are related and thus is precisely the relation itself